# inherited_resources and multiple belongs_to without nesting

Tags: belongs-to, nested, inherited-resources

Let's get down to brass tacks.

Rails: **2.3.11**

I have a controller using inherited_resources to reference two separate and non-nested resources.

My controller is as shown:

```
class Tools::DeploymentLinesController < ToolsController
  inherit_resources
  belongs_to :deployment
  belongs_to :ticket
end#Tools::DeploymentLinesController
```

However, `inherit_resources` is assuming that the `belongs_to :ticket` is a nested resource of `deployment`.

Is there any way of using two `belongs_to` in my controller **without** nesting? Or do I need to write out my own business logic to account for a missing inherited_resources association?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use:

```
belongs_to :deployment, :ticket
```